# Elliptic Curve - Arithmetic overflow

Tags: rust, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to implement elliptic point doubling and addition in Rust, however, I'm running into arithmetic overflow, specifically at the line where the gradient is being calculated in the doubling function. Any ideas?

```
fn ec_point_double((x, y): (U256, U256)) -> (U256, U256) {
        let dec_gx = hex_to_dec("79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798");
        let gx: U256 = U256::from_dec_str(dec_gx.as_str()).unwrap();
        let dec_gy = hex_to_dec("483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8");
        let gy: U256 = U256::from_dec_str(dec_gy.as_str()).unwrap();
        let two: U256 = U256::from(2);
        let three: U256 = U256::from(3);
        let dec_n = hex_to_dec("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F");
        let n: U256 = U256::from_dec_str(dec_n.as_str()).unwrap();
        let lambda: U256 = (((((three % n) * (x % n)) % n * (x % n)) * two.mod_inverse(n)) % n
            * y.mod_inverse(n))
            % n;
        let new_x = ((lambda % n) * (lambda % n)) % n - ((x % n) * (two % n)) % n;
        let new_y: U256 =
            ((lambda % n * (x % n)) % n + (gy % n - (lambda % n * gx % n) % n) % n) % n;
        (new_x, new_y)
```

Initially I was getting arithmetic overflow because I used regular division, and not modular inverse. However, even when using modular inverse, still getting arithmetic overflow. Expecting no arithmetic overflow

Comment: First your formulas have many errors; see page 13 in https://secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf -- for a Weierstrass curve over an F_p field, which secp256k1 is; your code is irrelevant for other types of elliptic curves. Second, all arithmetic in these formulas must be done in the underlying field thus modulo its order p, not n (the order of the _curve group_); that means not only using the inverse for division, but also modular multiplications and additions/subtractions. Being antioxidant myself, I can't advise how to do that in Rust.

Comment: Oh my, thanks so much! Seems like I'll have to do more research :)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've updated my code to reflect the field p (which I've kept labeled n in my code). However, I'm still getting arithmetic overflow, specifically at the line where lambda is being calculated. Any tips? I've updated the code in the original post.